Troubleshooting SQLite Database Not Found in Android Project
I'm working on a Android Studio app using Java. I started working on the database today (SQLite Database) and I've created the myDatabaseHelper class.
package com.example.findyourworker;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "accounts.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "users_data";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addAccount(String username,String password,String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
        cv.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    boolean checkLogin(String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID};
        String selection = COLUMN_EMAIL + "=? AND " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        boolean loginSuccessful = cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return loginSuccessful;
    }

    boolean checkUsernameExists(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID};
        String selection = COLUMN_USERNAME + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {username};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        boolean usernameExists = cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return usernameExists;
    }

    boolean checkPasswordExists(String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID};
        String selection = COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {password};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        boolean passwordExists = cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return passwordExists;
    }

    boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID};
        String selection = COLUMN_EMAIL + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        boolean emailExists = cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return emailExists;
    }
}

And this is how I implemented the use of this DATABASE in the register page:
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Inside onClick, update variables based on input validation
                username = un.getText().toString();
                password = pass.getText().toString();
                email = em.getText().toString();

                unValid = !TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && isUsernameValid(username);
                passValid = !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && isValidPassword(password);
                emailValid = !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && isValidEmail(email);

                if (unValid && passValid && emailValid) {
                    // All fields are valid, proceed with the signup process
                    if (!myDB.checkUsernameExists(username) && !myDB.checkEmailExists(email)) {
                        myDB.addAccount(username.trim(), password.trim(), email.trim());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, fragments_host.class);
                        // startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        if (myDB.checkEmailExists(email) && myDB.checkUsernameExists(username)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Email and Username Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (myDB.checkUsernameExists(username)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Username Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (myDB.checkEmailExists(email)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Email Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle invalid input fields here
                    if (!unValid) {
                        un.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        vibrateDevice(signup.this, 200);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> un.setTextColor(Color.BLACK), 200);
                    }
                    if (!passValid) {
                        pass.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        vibrateDevice(signup.this, 200);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> pass.setTextColor(Color.BLACK), 200);
                    }
                    if (!emailValid) {
                        em.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        vibrateDevice(signup.this, 200);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> em.setTextColor(Color.BLACK), 200);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

And in the register it works. My problem is with the login page:
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myDB.checkEmailExists(email) && myDB.checkPasswordExists(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Login was Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, fragments_host.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Account doesn't exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

If anyone has any idea why the login page database connection is not working please leave a comment or an answer your help would be much appreciated!
I tried running pieces of the code by ChatGPT and everything looks correct. And I tried modifying the code a little and nothing worked. I also tried to locate the DATABASE and watch it live and I couldn't find it in the folders of my project.

You are not giving enough details about the error, stack trace, etc.

Well first of all thank you for reaching out to me. It’s not really an error just that when I register an account I try to login using that account and it doesn’t work. Sorry for not mentioning that in the past, and if you need any more details I’ll be happy to provide you with them to the best of my abilities.
